# Unable to access ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to remove GNOME from Ubuntu 14.04. I run following commands on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity gnome-shell lightdm

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install
```

After applying, I restarted my laptop and got the black screen asking for my username and password. Image of the screen is as follows:
[Image Of Screen](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2j4xees.jpg)

Please help me to sought this out. How can I get my Ubuntu 14.04 back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've removed `lightdm` package, which is the graphical login manager. What you got right now is TTY, virtual console. Login there and run

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

once that command is done, run

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

You will have your graphical login back.

Also, I see you've removed unity. This is the default graphical shell in Ubuntu. If you wanted to get rid of GNOME, removing `gnome-shell` would be sufficient. To install unity back, run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Without unity or gnome?

Comment: @Pilot6 yeah, I just noticed he also removed unity, and edited my answer

Comment: @Serg I am sorry for that actually I am new to Ubuntu so got little confused I am not able to run any command as I am getting black screen n internet is not connected at that moment to it because nothing got started where I can connect the Internet. Please guide me how to get back all

Comment: @Charu So you are at home and next to your router , right ? So because you've connected to the router before, your ubuntu should connect to it automatically. Run this command `iwconfig` and if you're connecting through wireless, take a lot at wlan0, where it says ESSID you should see the name of your network. That means you are connected.  `ping google.com` will confirm if you have internet access. If these two programs don't tell you anything, you can use another tool to actually connect  to wifi , it is called `nmcli`.  Let me know what ping and iwconfig tell you first

Comment: @Serg Actually yesterday my internet stopped working, just got it repaired. The iwconfig ping me with the following. I am attaching image of what is pinged[http://oi57.tinypic.com/2ivi9fn.jpg]

Comment: @Serg Thanks it helped me out. Its working now!

Answer (score 0):

You removed all desktop environments. That is why you can not start any ;-)

You can restore this by running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This will restore lightdm and unity as well.